# get wmiobject win32: how do I email the output

Tags: powershell, email, office365, get-wmiobject

I have everything in place at least I think so. I want to email myself the output of a Get-WmiObject win32 command. example:

```
$OS = "."
(Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).Name |Out-String

 $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "mypassword" -AsPlainText -Force
    $mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 
("support@myemail.com", $secpasswd)

    Send-MailMessage -To "support@myemail.com" -SmtpServer 
"smtp.office365.com" -Credential $mycreds -UseSsl "Backup Notification" -
Body $body -From "support@myemail.com"
```

I have tried the following:

```
$body = (
  Write-Host "Computer Info:" -Message $PCinfo
  ) -join "`r`n"
    Write-Verbose -Message $body
```

That returns the error: "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Body'. The argument is null or empty."

Any direction, advice, or examples would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Write-Host` bypasses the usual PowerShell data route (the pipeline); you may want to look into [`Get-Help Out-String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) or [`Get-Help Out-Default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/out-default) for possible alternatives.

In bypassing the pipeline with `Write-Host`, you leave the assignment to `$body` "empty" - that is, there is no data to assign to the variable. Since `$null` is a legal value for a variable to have, this will not throw an error, until the variable is used in a context where a null value is not permitted (such as with `Send-MailMessage`).

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 2):

This format give you some richer information. This takes the content of the `Win32_OperatingSystem` class and converts it into a HTML table, appending it to a `$body` variable, with your "Computer Info:" text above it:

```
$body = "Computer Info: <br>"
$body += Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | ConvertTo-HTML -Fragment
```

Effectively recreate `$body` by piping it to `Out-String`. This ensures it's a string object, which the `-Body` parameter of `Send-MailMessage` requires:

```
$Body = $Body | Out-String
```

Finally, when calling `Send-MailMessage` use the -BodyAsHTML parameter to ensure the email is sent as a HTML email:

```
Send-MailMessage -To "support@myemail.com" -From "support@myemail.com" -SmtpServer "smtp.office365.com" -Credential $mycreds -UseSsl "Backup Notification" -Body $body -BodyAsHTML
```